# Нужна помощь с formatter(новичок)

Tags: java, json

Нужна помощь у меня есть задание, нужно сделать что-бы когда выводит текст выводился не так:

> Euro|EUR|9,006.6631
>
> British Pound Sterling|GBP|7,966.1384
>
> United States Dollar|USD|9,717.7182

А вот так:

[image]

Это вроде не сложно, спасибо сразу|

Тут ещё lib: json-20190722.jar
вот код:

```
package com.company;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        System.out.println(url);

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            response.append('\n');
        }

        System.out.print(response.toString());

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

        JSONObject bpiObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("bpi");

        for (int i = 0; i < bpiObject.length(); i++) {
            String key = bpiObject.names().get(i).toString();
            JSONObject currencyObject = bpiObject.getJSONObject(key);
            System.out.println(currencyObject.getString("description") + "|" + currencyObject.getString("code") + "|" + currencyObject.getString("rate"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно через Formatter

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf(
    ">%-30s|%-6s|%,14.4f", 
    currencyObject.getString("description"), 
    currencyObject.getString("code"), 
    Double.parseDouble(currencyObject.getString("rate"))
);
```

Comment: У меня выбивает ошибку, как это исправить
CurrencyObject и getString красные

Comment: изменил ответ под ваш случай

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8,854.3637"
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:49)

Comment: Ну оставьте курс в виде строки `%15s` например. Уберите `Double.parseDouble`. У вас видимо какая-нибдудь русская система форматов в системе, когда `.` - разделитель триад, а `,` - разделитель дробной и целой части