# Помогите с formatter(newbie)

Tags: java, url, request

Нужно сделать чтобы когда выводит текст выводился не так.
Можно через `formatter`, можно через `printf`.

> Euro|EUR|9,006.6631
>
> British Pound Sterling|GBP|7,966.1384
>
> United States Dollar|USD|9,717.7182

А вот так:

[image]

Это вроде не сложно, спасибо сразу|

Тут ещё lib: `json-20190722.jar`

вот код:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        System.out.println(url);

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            response.append('\n');
        }

        System.out.print(response.toString());

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

        JSONObject bpiObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("bpi");

        for (int i = 0; i < bpiObject.length(); i++) {
            String key = bpiObject.names().get(i).toString();
            JSONObject currencyObject = bpiObject.getJSONObject(key);
            System.out.println(currencyObject.getString("description") + "|" + currencyObject.getString("code") + "|" + currencyObject.getString("rate"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут же ответили! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125621/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d1%81-formatter%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%be%d0%ba

Answer (score 3):

Тут вроде все просто:

```
System.out.printf(
    ">%-25s|%-5s|%,10f",
    currencyObject.getString("description"),
    currencyObject.getString("code"),
    currencyObject.getDouble("rate_float")
);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Главное, чтобы в `description` не нашлось строки больше 25 символом, иначе некрасивая таблица будет :) как вариант, можно найти максимальное количество символов среди всех `description`, а потом уже построить строку-шаблон

Comment: @gil9red  там в ответе 3 валюты прилетает, все поля description нам известны

Comment: Действительно, в https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json только валюты из вопроса